# Issue with xdebug.remote_connect_back reset while debugging php code in vagrant box using PhpStorm

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a vagrant box with CentOS 6.4, Apache 2.4 and php 5.6.
I have also installed Zend extension and Xdebug 2.3.3
I have configured PhpStorm IDE on my MAC to use Vagrant box for debugging using XDEBUG.

The steps for setting up PhpStorm with Vagrant can be found [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Getting+started+with+Vagrant+in+PhpStorm).
The steps for using Xdebug with PhpStorm can be found [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm#Zero-configurationWebApplicationDebuggingwithXdebugandPhpStorm-3.Setabreakpointinthesourcecode).

Vagrant box setup will have several individual config file which gets included in the final php.ini. We have used puppet for provisioning.

So the setup is successful. I can debug the code using "Start listening for PHP Debug connection" as explained in the links above.

Here are the parameters for xdebug as I have configured, tested and successfully working (except for the weird behavior I have explained below) :

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.idekey = pass1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
```

Here is my problem or weired behavior I have been observing...
It appears that somehow ***xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1*** is resetting to value of **0** after few minutes automatically.

After **xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0** , I am unable to debug. 
So I have to manually set it back to 1 and then restart the apache httpd.

**Has anyone come across this problem and is there a way to resolve this?**

Comment: Do you have some type of continuous integration going? is there a puppet/chef relationship here? That file is definitely not changing due to *phantom activity*, there's a good reason for it.

Comment: Why not configure `remote_host` with right IP as well? This way even if `remote_connect_back` will somehow become `0` xdebug will still use right IP.

Comment: @LazyOne The vagrant box is install locally. So it sees the incoming IP as 127.0.0.1. I found that the only way to check and pass "Web Server debug config" in PHPStorm is with the setting I have posted in the question. Otherwise I am not able to debug the session.

Comment: @Andy Please provide xdebug log when debugging works.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  I found out that puppet service was modifying the xdebug.ini. I stopped the puppet service and so far everything working fine.

Comment: I figured that there was some type of provisioning going on that was causing this issue. Instead, you shouldn't disable puppet, you should modify the puppet task at hand to have correctly default settings.